# Iptables showing 0:0 in counters

Tags: linux, iptables, fail2ban

I'm currently logging port 22 connections with iptables:

```
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp -m multiport --dports 22,NNN,NNN -m state --state NEW -j LOG --log-prefix "SSH Connection " --log-level 1
```

and have a Fail2Ban jail set up to ban all connection attempts to port 22. However, a lot of entries in my iptables listings show 0:0 (0 hits, 0 packets).

How can someone connect to this port without iptables incrementing the counter(s)?

Comment: We don't know. Your iptables rule cannot be understood in isolation. We would need to see the whole chain.

Comment: the `-A` option adds that new rule, **after all existing rules** and the context of those previous rules determines if the new rule will ever be applicable or not

Answer (score 1):

With iptables, the first rule that matches wins. You almost certainly have an earlier rule that is affecting your packets.

Comment: I don't. Everything is allowed unless it's not. I think I know what's happening and will answer my own question.

Answer (score 0):

This is likely a product of SYN scanning:

[Port Scanner article on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_scanner#SYN_scanning)

> SYN scan is another form of TCP scanning. Rather than using the operating system's network functions, the port scanner generates raw IP packets itself, and monitors for responses. This scan type is also known as "half-open scanning", because it never actually opens a full TCP connection. The port scanner generates a SYN packet. If the target port is open, it will respond with a SYN-ACK packet. The scanner host responds with an RST packet, closing the connection before the handshake is completed.[3] If the port is closed but unfiltered, the target will instantly respond with an RST packet.
>
> The use of raw networking has several advantages, giving the scanner full control of the packets sent and the timeout for responses, and allowing detailed reporting of the responses. There is debate over which scan is less intrusive on the target host. SYN scan has the advantage that the individual services never actually receive a connection. However, the RST during the handshake can cause problems for some network stacks, in particular simple devices like printers. There are no conclusive arguments either way.